# How to know the "level" of shells I am in?

Tags: shell, terminal

If I open a terminal like `xterm` I will have a shell. Then if I use `ssh` or `zsh` I will have another "level" of shell. Is there a way to know how many times I have to `Ctrl+D` or type `exit` to exit all of them? My real intention is to exit everything except the "root" shell.

It will also be nice to know what effect(s) terminal multiplexers (like `screen`) have on the solution.

PS: Please feel free to change the title, I don't know if those are the correct terms.

Comment: See also [How many shells deep I am?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/373704/80216)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One (admittedly not perfect) way is to add the result of `ps --no-headers -o comm $PPID` to your shell prompt. This will tell you the name of the process that spawned your shell. If you're inside a nested zsh, it will say "zsh". If you're inside a top-level zsh, it will read "xterm" or "screen" or whatever your shell is running in.

To tell whether you're inside an ssh or su session, you can simply look at the hostname and username part of your prompt.

When you're running nested screens (which I don't imagine is a common situation), there's no way I can think of to tell whether you're in the top-level shell of a nested screen, or the top-level shell of the top-level screen. You could configure screen to always display a status line, which would cause multiple status lines to be displayed, if you're in nested screens.

Comment: Aaah... snap.. beat me to it. :) +1

Comment: Currently I'm on a mac and the command gave me `ps: illegal option -- -`, any idea why? I'll test it again in Linux soon :)

Comment: @phunehehe: `--option-name` is mostly a GNU-specific features, so is mostly not available in standard system utilities outside Linux. But you can get the effect of `ps --no-headers` portably by adding `=` after the column name. Also the `comm` column is not POSIX, but the `cmd` column (which includes the arguments of the command) is. Also `-p` is necessary before the PID in POSIX syntax. Hence `ps -o cmd= -p $PPID` is portable and gives similar information.

Comment: confirmed, works on Gentoo

Comment: @phunehehe: sorry, I made a mistake in the comment above. In fact the `comm` column is specified by POSIX and documented on Mac OS X, whereas the `cmd` column exists on Linux but is not standard.

Comment: This, however, is supported by OS X: `ps -o comm= $PPID`

Answer (score 46):

You have in fact hit upon the correct term¹. There is an environment variable `SHLVL` which all major interactive shells (bash, tcsh, zsh) increment by 1 when they start. So if you start a shell inside a shell, `SHLVL` increases by 1.

This doesn't directly answer your concern, however, because `SHLVL` carries over things like terminal emulators. For example, in my typical configuration, `$SHLVL` is 2 in an xterm, because level 1 corresponds to the shell that runs my X session (`~/.xinitrc` or `~/.xsession`).

What I do is to display `$SHLVL` in my prompt, but only if the parent process of the shell is another shell (with heuristics like “if its name ends in `sh` plus optional punctuation and digits, it's a shell”). That way, I have an obvious visual indication in the uncommon case of a shell running under another shell.

Maybe you would prefer to detect shells that are running directly under a terminal emulator. 
You can do this fairly accurately: these are the shells whose parent process has a different controlling terminal, so that `ps -o tty= -p$$` and `ps -o tty= -p$PPID` produce different output. You might manually reset `SHLVL` to 1 in these shells, or set your own `TERMSHLVL` to 1 in these shells (and incremented otherwise).

¹ 
<sub>Although one wouldn't think it looking at the manual pages: none of the three shells that support it include the word “level” in their documentation of `SHLVL`.</sub>

Comment: Thanks for confirming the term. I'm still on a mac and surprised to find those 2 commands give the same result, regardless of my shell level.

Comment: @phunehehe: what 2 commands? If you mean `ps -o tty= -p$pid`, this shows the process's controlling terminal, which identifies the terminal emulator (xterm, screen, sshd, …) that the process is running in. It will not change if you start a shell from another shell, but will change if you start a new terminal emulator. If the terminal emulator is a native Mac application, there may be a Mac-specific subtlety that I'm unaware of.

Comment: `ps -o tty= -p$$ ` and `ps -o tty= -p$PPID `, because you said they should produce different output. Or did I misunderstand something?

Comment: @phunehehe: They give different output when if the parent process of the shell is a terminal emulator, because the terminal emulator doesn't have its emulated terminal as a controlling terminal. If you find otherwise, please post the output of `ps -p $$ -p $PPID` (again, I have no OSX experience, so maybe there's something unusual going on on OSX).

Comment: @Gilles: that was indeed something unusual with OSX. I tested on Gentoo and everything was correct as you said. On OSX, `ps -p $$ -p $PPID` gives (sorry I don't know how to format comments)
  PID TTY           TIME CMD
  209 ttys000    0:00.01 login -pf phunehehe
  210 ttys000    0:00.12 -bash

Comment: Not that this is a surprise, but SHLVL didn't work that way on SunOS 4.1.3, FYI.  :D

Comment: @Kevin: Oops. Thanks, I just checked, and ksh in fact doesn't document SHLVL because it doesn't actually have that feature. (I thought that was where it came from, but clearly not.)

Comment: Seems to come [from tcsh or at least some tcsh patch (possibly) by Paul Placeway that also introduced a command line editor in 1984](https://groups.google.com/forum/message/raw?msg=net.sources/3eER9GEdo2c/B9G1KGziIx4J). (and _level_ was mentioned there)

Answer (score 1):

Not very elegant, but you could use *tree view* in [htop](http://htop.sourceforge.net/) to see parent-child relationship of your shell to other running proccesses.

```
$ htop # then press 't' and scroll around or 'Ctrl-W' to find your shell proccess
```

And use that to deduce the ammount of shells you will need to exit, before ariving at the "root" shell

Answer (score 1):

You can use the environment variable *SHLVL*:

```
echo "$SHLVL"
```

Comment: If you use `ssh` e.g. to the same account this will still be `1`

Answer (score 0):

I find that

```
$ pstree -u | grep ${USER}
```

can be quite helpful for seeing where I "fit in" on a system. I prefer it over `pstree -u ${USER}`.

Occasionally it will remind me that I left a `nohup` job running, or similar.

(Also, I use `alias grep='grep --color=auto'`.)