# Bash: How many nested sessions deep?

Tags: bash, environment-variables

Say I start a `bash` shell,
...and then another `bash` session from within that shell,
...and then another `bash` session from within that session,
...and then another `bash` session from within that session,
...(times N) etc

To exit all N sessions I have to type `exit` N times.

How do I find out how deep I am nested from within any given bash session?

Ideally I'm looking for some environment variable similar to `$STY` for screen sessions.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use `SHLVL`. From `man bash` :

```
SHLVL  Incremented by one each time an instance of bash is started.
```

**Example :**

```
$ echo $SHLVL
1
$ bash
$ echo $SHLVL
2
$ bash
$ echo $SHLVL
3
```

Comment: This is good, but I've noticed a slight problem with my setup: - my .xinitrc starts one shell as a regular process, but another using `exec` (so that when this terminal closes, the entire XSession ends). `$SHLVL` produces two different numbers for these terminals. Is there an environment variable that is more shell-specific?

Comment: `$BASH_SUBSHELL` looked promising, but doesn't deliver.

Comment: @tetris11Yeah..thats how `SHLVL` works..check [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/3217/125975) solution if it fits..

Comment: Ah, of course - I can manually set `SHLVL=0` in `~/.xinitrc`. Brilliant, thanks