# How many shells deep I am?

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, vim, zsh

**Problem**: Find how many shells deep I am.

**Details**:
I open the shell from vim a lot. Build and run and exit. Sometimes I forget and open another vim inside and then yet another shell. :(

I want to know how many shells deep I am, perhaps even have it on my shell screen at all times. (I can manage that part).

**My solution**: Parse the process tree and look for vim and bash/zsh and figure out the current process's depth within it.

Does something like that already exist? I could not find anything.

Comment: Is the `$SHLVL` variable (maintained by several shells) what you're looking for?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, I did not know about this one! Yeah this is very close. It, however does not count vim. But, now I can try something with this. ;)

Comment: To clarify, you're not really interested in how many (directly nested) shells, indicated by SHLVL, but whether your current shell is a descendant of vim?

Comment: @JeffSchaller, more like, how many total layers deep I am. vim > shell > vim > shell > vim > shell would mean 6 layers. It could be shell > shell > shell > vim. 
The most comprehensive result would be if I know a counter like vim : 3 , shell : 4. And I put the results in my shell prompt. like `:v:3;s:4:master~/directory/seconddirectory/  ` could be my prompt.

I can do the prompt bit, but I am hesitant to add a script of my own if it turns out to be a feature that exists and I do not know.

Comment: Have you considered binding for instance F12 to the build command within vim? Just an alternative solution to the underlying problem: map <F12> :make<cr>

Comment: This seems to be a bit of an XY problem - my workflow is ^Z to escape from the vim instance into the parent shell, and `fg` to get back, which doesn't have this issue.

Comment: @Alexander, yes I have those set but a lot of these times, I have to vary the arguments passed, for instance timestamps, UUID of a device. It is not feasible to do this with a command.

Comment: @Doorknob, I do that too. but I prefer this one, because then I would have to keep checking "jobs". and There can be many running at times on my machine. now, add TMUX with the equation. It become complex and overflowing. If I spawn shell inside vim, it would be less of a scatter. (However I end up making the mess and hence the question).

Comment: @Doorknob: With all due respect, that seems like responding to the question, “How do I drive from point A from point B?” with the suggestion, “Don’t drive; just take an Uber.”  If the user has a workflow that involves editing multiple files concurrently, then having multiple parallel stopped ``vim`` jobs might be more confusing than having a stack of nested processes.  By the by, I prefer having multiple *windows*, so I can easily jump back and forth quickly, but I wouldn’t call this an XY problem just because I prefer a different workflow.

Comment: Must you go deeper?

Comment: @MateenUlhaq, late reply, sorry. Yes, it is easier to manage everything if I open a shell from inside vim and close it after doing my stuff. Unfortunately I am tempted to do another vim for quick config lookups or quick changes (which stretch at times). Sometimes I leave my vim-shell on and go for lunch and forget it was a shell inside vim.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

When I read your question, my first thought was `$SHLVL`. 
Then I saw that you wanted to count `vim` levels
*in addition to* shell levels. 
A simple way to do this is to define a shell function:

```
vim()  { ( ((SHLVL++)); command vim  "$@");}
```

This will automatically and silently increment `SHLVL`
each time you type a `vim` command. 
You will need to do this for each variant of `vi`/`vim` that you ever use; e.g.,

```
vi()   { ( ((SHLVL++)); command vi   "$@");}
view() { ( ((SHLVL++)); command view "$@");}
```

The outer set of parentheses creates a subshell,
so the manual change in the value of `SHLVL`
doesn’t contaminate the current (parent) shell environment. 
Of course the `command` keyword is there to prevent the functions
from calling themselves (which would result in an infinite recursion loop). 
And of course you should put these definitions
into your `.bashrc` or other shell initialization file.

---

There’s a slight inefficiency in the above. 
In some shells (bash being one), if you say

```
(cmd1; cmd2; …; cmdn)
```

where `cmdn` is an external, executable program
(i.e., not a built-in command), the shell keeps an extra process lying around,
just to wait for `cmdn` to terminate. 
This is (arguably) not necessary;
the advantages and disadvantages are debatable. 
If you don’t mind tying up a bit of memory and a process slot
(and to seeing one more shell process than you need when you do a `ps`),
then do the above and skip to the next section. 
Ditto if you’re using a shell that doesn’t keep the extra process lying around. 
But, if you want to avoid the extra process, a first thing to try is

```
vim()  { ( ((SHLVL++)); exec vim  "$@");}
```

The `exec` command is there to prevent the extra shell process from lingering.

But, there’s a gotcha. 
The shell’s handling of `SHLVL` is somewhat intuitive:
When the shell starts, it checks whether `SHLVL` is set. 
If it’s not set (or set to something other than a number),
the shell sets it to 1. 
If it is set (to a number), the shell adds 1 to it.

But, by this logic, if you say `exec sh`, your `SHLVL` should go up. 
But that’s undesirable, because your real shell level hasn’t increased. 
The shell handles this by ***subtracting one*** from `SHLVL`
when you do an `exec`:

```
$ echo "$SHLVL"
1

$ set | grep SHLVL
SHLVL=1

$ env | grep SHLVL
SHLVL=1

$ (env | grep SHLVL)
SHLVL=1

$ (env) | grep SHLVL
SHLVL=1

$ (exec env) | grep SHLVL
SHLVL=0
```

So

```
vim()  { ( ((SHLVL++)); exec vim  "$@");}
```

is a wash; it increments `SHLVL` only to decrement it again.
You might as well just say `vim`, without benefit of a function.

> **Note:**
>   [According to Stéphane Chazelas (who knows everything)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/373704/23408#373710),
>   some shells are smart enough *not* to do this if the `exec` is in a subshell.

To fix this, you would do

```
vim()  { ( ((SHLVL+=2)); exec vim  "$@");}
```

---

Then I saw that you wanted to count `vim` levels
***independently of*** shell levels. 
Well, the exact same trick works (well, with a minor modification):

```
vim() { ( ((SHLVL++, VILVL++)); export VILVL; exec vim "$@");}
```

(and so on for `vi`, `view`, etc.) 
The `export` is necessary
because `VILVL` isn’t defined as an environment variable by default. 
But it doesn’t need to be part of the function;
you can just say `export VILVL` as a separate command (in your `.bashrc`). 
And, as discussed above, if the extra shell process isn’t an issue for you,
you can do `command vim` instead of `exec vim`, and leave `SHLVL` alone:

```
vim() { ( ((VILVL++)); command vim "$@");}
```

> **Personal Preference:**
>   You may want to rename `VILVL` to something like `VIM_LEVEL`. 
>   When I look at “`VILVL`”, my eyes hurt;
>   they can’t tell whether it’s a misspelling of “vinyl”
>   or a malformed Roman numeral.

---

If you are using a shell that doesn’t support `SHLVL` (e.g., dash),
you can implement it yourself as long as the shell implements a startup file. 
Just do something like

```
if [ "$SHELL_LEVEL" = "" ]
then
    SHELL_LEVEL=1
else
    SHELL_LEVEL=$(expr "$SHELL_LEVEL" + 1)
fi
export SHELL_LEVEL
```

in your `.profile` or applicable file. 
(You should probably not use the name `SHLVL`, as that will cause chaos
if you ever start using a shell that supports `SHLVL`.)

---

Other answers have addressed the issue
of embedding environment variable value(s) into your shell prompt,
so I won’t repeat that, especially you say you already know how to do it.

Comment: I’m somewhat puzzled that so many answers suggest executing an external executable program, like `ps` or `pstree`, when you can do this with shell builtins.

Comment: This answer is perfect. I have marked this as the solution (unfortunately it does not have that many votes yet).

Comment: Your approach is amazing and you are using only the primitives which means including this in my .profile/.shellrc would not break anything. I pull those on any machine I work on.

Comment: Note that `dash` has arithmetic expansion. `SHELL_LEVEL=$((SHELL_LEVEL + 1))` should be enough even if $SHELL_LEVEL was previously unset or empty. It's only if you had to be portable to the Bourne shell that you'd need to resort to `expr`, but then you'd also need to replace `$(...)` with `\`..\``. `SHELL_LEVEL=\`expr "${SHELL_LEVEL:-0}" + 1\``

Comment: About SHLVL and (possibly implicit) exec, see https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2016-09/msg00000.html  http://www.zsh.org/mla/workers/2016/msg01574.html http://bugs.gw.com/view.php?id=572

Comment: Also note that using environment variables in arithmetic expressions amounts to a command injection vulnerability in cases where the environment is not trusted. Try `VILVL='psvar[0`echo Oops>&2`]' "$SHELL" -c '((VILVL++))'` for instance. So you may want to check that those variables are only decimal integers first.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, I did not know about command injection this way. But, if the environment is not trusted, and the exploit already has the ability to inject env-variables, why would it need to exploit me?
I get the technical possibility of this happening, but not the need, because the attacker already seems to control the machine.

Comment: @Pranay, it's unlikely to be a problem. If an attacker can inject _any_ arbitrary env var, then things like PATH/LD_PRELOAD are more obvious choices, but if non-problematic variables get through, like with sudo configured without reset_env (and one can force a `bash` script to read ~/.bashrc by making stdin a socket for instance), then that can become a problem. That's a lot of "if"s, but something to keep at the back of one's mind (unsanitized data in arithmetic context is dangerous)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas. Yeah, I see it now.

Answer (score 37):

You could count as many time you need to go up the process tree until you find a session leader. Like with `zsh` on Linux:

```
lvl() {
  local n=0 pid=$$ buf
  until
    IFS= read -rd '' buf < /proc/$pid/stat
    set -- ${(s: :)buf##*\)}
    ((pid == $4))
  do
    ((n++))
    pid=$2
  done
  echo $n
}
```

Or POSIXly (but less efficient):

```
lvl() (
  unset IFS
  pid=$$ n=0
  until
    set -- $(ps -o ppid= -o sid= -p "$pid")
    [ "$pid" -eq "$2" ]
  do
    n=$((n + 1)) pid=$1
  done
  echo "$n"
)
```

That would give 0 for the shell that was started by your terminal emulator or getty and one more for each descendant.

You only need to do that once on startup. For instance with:

```
PS1="[$(lvl)]$PS1"
```

in your `~/.zshrc` or equivalent to have it in your prompt.

`tcsh` and several other shells (`zsh`, `ksh93`, `fish` and `bash` at least) maintain a `$SHLVL` variable which they increment on startup (and decrement before running another command with `exec` (unless that `exec` is in a subshell if they're not buggy (but many are))). That only tracks the amount of *shell* nesting though, not process nesting. Also level 0 is not guaranteed to be the session leader.

Comment: Yeah.. this or similar. I did not wish to write this of my own, and it was not my intention to have anyone write this for me. :(. I was hoping for some feature in vim or shell or some plugin that is regularly maintained.  I searched but did not find something.

Answer (score 34):

Use `echo $SHLVL`. Use the [KISS principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle). Depending on your program's complexity, this may be enough.

Comment: Works for `bash`, but not for `dash`.

Comment: SHLVL does not help me. I knew about it, and it also came up in the search when I searched. :)
There are more details in the question.

Comment: @Pranay Are you certain vim itself does not provide this information?

Comment: @user2497, I am somewhat. This is the premise of the question. I searched everywhere, I was aware of SHLVL too. I wanted -- > a) be certain there is no such thing. b) do it with least amount of dependencies/maintenance.

Answer (score 17):

One potential solution is to look at the output of `pstree`. When run inside a shell that was spawned from within `vi`, the part of the tree tree that lists `pstree` should show you how deep you are. For example:

```
$ pstree <my-user-ID>
...
       ├─gnome-terminal-─┬─bash───vi───sh───vi───sh───pstree
...
```

Comment: Yeah that is what I suggested as my solution (in the question). I do not wish to parse the pstree though :(. this is good for manually reading it, I was thinking of writing a program to do it for me and let me know. I am not very inclined to write a parser if a plugin/tool already does it :).

Answer (score 12):

#### First variant - shell depth only.

Simple solution for `bash`: add to the `.bashrc` next two lines (or change your current `PS1` value):

```
PS1="${SHLVL} \w\$ "
export PS1
```

**Result:**

```
1 ~$ bash
2 ~$ bash
3 ~$ exit
exit
2 ~$ exit
exit
1 ~$
```

Number at the beginning of prompt string will be denote shell level.

#### Second variant, with nested vim and shell levels both.

add this lines to the `.bashrc`

```
branch=$(pstree -ls $$)
vim_lvl=$(grep -o vim <<< "$branch" | wc -l)
sh_lvl=$(grep -o bash <<< "$branch" | wc -l)
PS1="v:${vim_lvl};s:$((sh_lvl - 1)):\w\$ "
export PS1
```

**Result:**

```
v:0;s:1:/etc$ bash
v:0;s:2:/etc$ bash
v:0;s:3:/etc$ vim
##### do ':sh' command in the vim, shell level is increasing by 1
v:1;s:4:/etc$ vim
##### do ':sh' command in the vim, shell level is increasing by 1
v:2;s:5:/etc$ bash
v:2;s:6:/etc$
```

v:1 - vim depth level
s:3 - shell depth level

Comment: this will give me the bash nesting. It won't give me the vim nests. :)

Comment: @Pranay Check the new solution. It doing what you want.

Comment: Yeah, this is a good solution. I can add more shells and it would work :).

Answer (score 8):

In the question you mentioned parsing of `pstree`. Here is a relatively simple way:

```
bash-4.3$ pstree -Aals $$ | grep -E '^ *`-((|ba|da|k|c|tc|z)sh|vim?)( |$)'
                  `-bash
                      `-bash --posix
                          `-vi -y
                              `-dash
                                  `-vim testfile.txt
                                      `-tcsh
                                          `-csh
                                              `-sh -
                                                  `-zsh
                                                      `-bash --norc --verbose
```

The `pstree` options:

- `-A` - ASCII output for easier filtering (in our case every command is preceded by `` `- ``)
- `-a` - show also command arguments, as a side-effect every command is shown on a separate line and we can easily filter the output using `grep`
- `-l` - do not truncate long lines
- `-s` - show parents of the selected process 
  (unfortunately not supported in old versions of `pstree`)
- `$$` - the selected process - the PID of the current shell

Comment: Yeah I was doing this pretty much. I also had something to count "bash" and "vim" etc. I just did not wish to maintain it. It is also not feasible to have a lot of custom functionality when you have to switch over a lot of VM's and develop on them sometimes.

Answer (score 4):

This doesn't *strictly* answer the question but in many cases may make it unnecessary to do so:

When you first launch your shell, run `set -o ignoreeof`.  **Don't** put it in your `~/.bashrc`.

Make it a habit to type Ctrl-D when you think you are in the top level shell and want to be sure.

If you're *not* in the top level shell, Ctrl-D will signal "end of input" to the current shell and you will drop back one level.

If you *are* in the top level shell, you will get a message:

```
Use "logout" to leave the shell.
```

I use this *all the time* for chained SSH sessions, to make it easy to drop back to a specific level of the SSH chain.  It works for nested shells just as well.

Comment: This definitely helps and yes it will remove a lot of complications :).  I might just combine this with the accepted answer :)). Conditionally set, so I might not have to look at my prompt all the time.